# Wordpress - displaying content from different tags in the page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, tags

I'm trying to have a page in my site (not the home page) that will display excerpts of posts from different tags. It's a page that displays different "topics" and I would like to have each topic displaying all of its relevant posts so far.

To make it easier, here is the page: http://www.thephotographyreview.com/sample-page/camera-reviews

Under each camera brand I want to display the posts related to it, without having to copy/paste every new post I make.

How can I retrieve the content I want using a code in the page/post editor? Does Wordpress even allow it?

I found a few threads here that discuss the topic, but none of the codes in them worked for me. I know html well enough to get by, but I don't know php at all. Maybe the answers in these threads only showed small sections of a longer code that I should have used? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of plugins that could achieve this for you.

See this one : http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/

Shortcodes are used in content. Read more here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API